# Ruby syntax: break out from 'each.. do..' block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing a **Ruby on Rails** app. My question is more about **Ruby** syntax.

I have a model class with a class method `self.check`:

```
class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.check(name)
     self.all.each do |car|
          #if result is true, break out from the each block, and return the car how to...
          result = SOME_CONDITION_MEET?(car) #not related with database
     end

     puts "outside the each block."
  end
end
```

I would like to stop/break out from the `each` block **once** the `result` is **true** (that's break the `each` block if `car.name` is the same as the `name` parameter **once**) AND return the `car` which cause the **true** result. How to break out in Ruby code?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can break with the `break` keyword. For example

```
[1,2,3].each do |i|
  puts i
  break
end
```

will output `1`. Or if you want to directly return the value, use `return`.

Since you updated the question, here the code:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  # …

  def self.check(name)
    self.all.each do |car|
      return car if some_condition_met?(car)
    end

    puts "outside the each block."
  end
end
```

Though you can also use `Array#detect` or `Array#any?` for that purpose.

Answer (score 15):

> I provide a bad sample code. I am not directly find or check something
>   from database. I just need a way to break out from the "each" block if
>   some condition meets once and return that 'car' which cause the true
>   result.

Then what you need is:

```
def check(cars, car_name)
  cars.detect { |car| car.name == car_name }
end
```

If you wanted just to know if there was any car with that name then you'd use `Enumerable#any?`. As a rule of thumb, use `Enumerable#each` only to do side effects, not perform logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `break` but what your are trying to do could be done much easier, like this:

```
def self.check(name)
  return false if self.find_by_name(name).nil?
  return true
end
```

This uses the database. You are trying to use Ruby at a place the database can deal with it better.

You can also use `break` conditional:

```
break if (car.name == name)
```

Comment: I provide a bad sample code. I am not directly find or check something from database. I just need a way to break out from the "each" block if some condition meets once and return that 'car' which cause the true result.

Comment: Well, you can even improve this : `def self.check(name); self.where(:name => name).any?; end`

Comment: the first snippet can be written: `!!self.find_by_name(name)`.

Comment: @tokland => I didnt edit the answer because the thread opener just posted this as an example and the core question is how to break an each not how to check if a dataset with the same name already exists. But anywhere nice code. I never thougt about double negation in coding before^^

Comment: @Mellon: Then you should update the question to reflect what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `include?` method.

```
def self.check(name)
  cars.include? name
end
```

`include?` returns `true` if `name` is present in the `cars` array else it returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this exact same thing and I was drawing a blank. So despite this being a very old question, here's my answer:

**Note: This answer assumes you don't want to return the item as it exists within the array, but instead do some processing on the item and return the result of that instead.** That's how I originally read the question, I realise now that was incorrect - though this approach can be easily modified for that effect (`break item` insead of `break output`)

Since returning from blocks is dodgy (nobody likes it, and I think the rules are about to change which makes it even more fraught) this is a much nicer option:

```
collection.inject(nil) do |_acc, item|
  output = expensive_operation(item)
  break output if output
end
```

Note that there are lots of variants; for example, if you don't want an incidental variable, and don't mind starting a second loop in some circumstances, you can invert it like this:

```
collection.inject(nil) do |acc, item|
  break acc if acc
  expensive_operation(item)
end
```