# Ruby - How to Execute something and then Break inside IF block?

Tags: ruby, debugging, break

**EDIT:** Someone pointed out that I needed to `break` correctly so I am editing the question
**Scenario:**
Please see following code:

```
print "UserID: "
uid = $stdin.gets.chomp
print "Password: "
pwd = $stdin.gets.chomp
usr_inp =  "#{uid};#{pwd}"
login_status = -1
# login_info.txt - "#{userid};#{password}" - format
File.open(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'login_info.txt'), "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
        puts line
        if (line.chomp == usr_inp)
            login_status = 1
        elsif (line.chomp != usr_inp && line.include?(uid)) #case a person inputs invalid password
            login_status = 0
        elsif (line.chomp != usr_inp && !(line.include?(uid))) #case a person inputs an invalid id
            login_status = 2
        end
    end
end
if (login_status == 1)
    puts "\nLogged in successfully: #{uid}"
elsif (login_status == 2)
    puts "\nSorry, that Employee does not exist."
elsif (login_status == 0)
    puts "\nLogin failed.\nPlease check credentials."
end
```

**Problem:**
`break if (condition)` exists in Ruby. But I don't waht that.
I want to do something like:

```
if (condition x)
    (do something)
    break
elsif (condition y)
    (do something else)
    break
else
    (whatever)
end
```

Maybe I am not understanding how ruby code works. Whenever I try to put the `break` as I want to use it, it associates with the next `elsif`.
**Please help.**

Comment: You should break out of the loop if the correct user id and password are found, otherwise the next line will be checked and be incorrect.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: yes, there is this problem, I cannot break in ruby. There is a "break if (condition)" but that does not allow executing a block level statement like "login_status = 1". How to break and execute something at the same time?

Comment: Can't you just use `break`, by itself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502397/ruby-syntax-break-out-from-each-do-block

Comment: You certainly can break in Ruby. If you want `login_status` to be visible outside the block, you need to initialize it outside (before) the block. You don't need to "break and execute something at the same time." Execute something, then break.

Comment: @Jordan: Exactly. Oh sorry `login_status` is already initialized outside in my original code at home. But as you mentioned. I need to execute something and break. Like `if (x), then do (y) break` - but I can't find that in ruby.

Comment: @JonnyHenly - I don't want the `break if (condition)`. I want to execute something such that `if (condition), then do something, then break`. Doesn't Ruby have anything functionally equivalent to this syntax?

Comment: Add `break` in a new line under the `login_saatus = 1` line.

Comment: `line.chomp!` once and then use `line`. There's no reason to `chomp` over and over and over and over again.

Comment: Instead of multiple `if (login_status == )` you could use `case login_status` and use `when`-statements,

Comment: @knut @tadman - I am already incorporating all your suggestions into my original code, but please help me with the `break`. I can't understand why I can't break it like in **C** or **Java**

Comment: @JonnyHenly has already explained the solution to your problem. You can do as many things as you want between `if` and `elsif`. Set `login_status` on one line and `break` on the next: `if condition1; do something; break; elsif condition2; do another thing; break; ...` (but with newlines instead of semicolons).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need and where you need it.

A script like this:

```
condition = 1
case condition
  when 1
    puts 'one'
    break
  when 2
    puts 'two'
  else
    puts 'Other %s' % condition
  end

puts 'end'
```

has a syntax error. `break` leaves a loop and there is no loop.

But with a loop, this works:

```
[1,2,3].each{|condition|
  case condition
    when 1
      puts 'one'
      break
    when 2
      puts 'two'
    else
      puts 'Other %s' % condition
    end
    puts 'end'
  }
  puts 'very end'
```

The output is:

```
one
very end
```

You see, the loop is stopped.

If you want to continue the loop with the next element, you need `next` (sorry, I'm just not aware what `break` is doing really in Java - it's been a long time since my last Java program):

```
[1,2,3].each{|condition|
  case condition
    when 1
      puts 'one'
      next
    when 2
      puts 'two'
    else
      puts 'Other %s' % condition
    end
    puts 'end %s' % condition
  }
  puts 'very end'
```

The result:

```
one
two
end 2
Other 3
end 3
very end
```

When you are not inside a loop (like in your code snippet), you may use `exit` (leave the program) or `return` (leave a method).

Comment: can a `File.each_line do... end` be considered a loop? Because I am trying to write the `if` conditions inside this `do... end` block

Comment: Just try it - and yes, it can.